# Trouble importing .ovpn file with Network Manager (GUI and CLI), and OpenVPN directly

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

The following my `.ovpn` file with parts of identifying information obfuscated with "blah". I've been trying to connect using Ubuntu 16.04.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote blah.blah.com
port 52424
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_blahblahblah name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
compress lz4
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blahblahblah
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blahblahblah
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
blahblahblah
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
blahblahblah
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

When I try to import this with `sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file blah.ovpn` I get the following.

```
Error: failed to import 'blah.ovpn': configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element (line 92).
```

Line 92 is where you see `<tls-crypt>`.

When I try `sudo openvpn --config blah.ovpn` I get the following.

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in blah.ovpn:15: compress (2.3.10)
```

Line 15 is `compress lz4`. When I comment this out and try again, I get the following.

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in blah.ovpn:20: tls-crypt (2.3.10)
```

Line 20 is just in two lines after `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` in the `<ca>` tag, which seems odd.

I've looked online and while I've seen *similar* errors I've not seen anyone having these exact problems that I have.

I created the `.ovpn` file on my Raspberry PI using `pivpn`. The generated files work smoothly on both my Windows machine, and my Android device, just not Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: i am having this issue too. did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: After I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, the GUI was still useless, however suddenly running `sudo openvpn --config blah.ovpn` worked from the command line. I'm guessing it was an updated version of OpenVPN.

Answer (score 1):

The `--compress` error is because Ubuntu uses OpenVPN 2.3.10, and 2.3.10 doesn't know about that directive.
`--compress` was added in 2.4.x.

In 2.3.x, LZO compression was the only compression method supported, via the `--comp-lzo` directive.
See https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos for info on adding the official OpenVPN repo so you can upgrade to the latest stable version (2.4.6 at the time this was posted).

`--tls-crypt` was also added in 2.4.x, so you would need to upgrade OpenVPN in order to use that as well.

However, Network Manager's OpenVPN plugin hasn't added support for `--compress` yet.
According to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/issues/1, `--compress` is still an open issue.  [This](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/blob/master/NEWS) does say that `--tls-crypt` was added in NM 1.2.10, but Ubuntu uses NM 1.2.6.